# It's necessary to save all API data in Redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I got a Problem, when I use redux-observable to handle asynchronous logic. Does I need to save all API data in Redux through redux-observable middleware to handle API event ? Or I just use axios as middleware to handle API event ?

Comment: Depend on your purpose, if data in API need to share to other component, you should save to redux store.

Comment: Can you clarify what "handle API event" means? What do you need to do? Generally speaking you only store in the redux store what the app needs to function. What's the point in wasting bits on data you don't use? This question needs more details, and what the actual problem *IS*.